# SQL Server How to add trigger to create same column in another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ddl, alter-table

I'm trying to figure out how to write a trigger that will add a newly created column to another table.

Situation: I have `dbo.tableA` and `dbo.tableA_Archive` tables.

When I add a column to `dbo.TableA` using this T-SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA 
    ADD [Column72] INT NULL
```

I need the trigger to add the same column to the `dbo.TableA_Archive` table as well.

I have not been able to find any examples that come close to doing this.

Comment: Why aren't you just adding the column to both tables as part of your deployment?

Comment: DDLTriggers and EVENTDATA() in order to extract/detect which changes

Comment: DDLTriggers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers EVENTDATA() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql

Comment: @Larnu, you suggested an easily solution :-). The next question from the topic-starter will, in my opinion, be something like "I need one DDL-trigger to catch all DDL_changes and replicate them somewhere"

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt for one second that this is some kind of [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), @Sergey .

Comment: Also, if you're using a temporal table, this behaviour is handled "automagically": [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ck6qsjhl)

Answer (score 0):

Since several commenters decided to just rag on me, and only @Bogdan Sahlean posted any thing of relevance, I'd give them credit, but they didn't post it as an answer.

Here is the final solution I came up with based on their guidance.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER AlterTable
ON DATABASE
AFTER ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @lv_xml_EventData XML,
        @lv_vc_SQLCMD VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @lv_xml_EventData = EVENTDATA()
    IF @lv_xml_EventData.value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','VARCHAR(200)') = 'TABLE'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
            @lv_vc_Table_Name VARCHAR(200) = @lv_xml_EventData.value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','VARCHAR(200)')
            
        IF @lv_vc_Table_Name = 'TableA'
        BEGIN
            SET @lv_vc_SQLCMD = @lv_xml_EventData.value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
            SET @lv_vc_SQLCMD = REPLACE(@lv_vc_SQLCMD,'TableA','TableA_Archive')
            BEGIN TRY
                EXEC (@lv_vc_SQLCMD)
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                THROW;
                ROLLBACK
            END CATCH
        END
    END
END
```

Now I know there are probably better ways to do this, but it does answer my question, and meet my needs.